# ARC and a window by thread

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I don't understand why a window created in a thread is still alive after thread's end (under ARC)?

This is called:

```
-(void)prefsWindow:(id)sender {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(200, 200, 640, 480);
    NSWindow *window  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                                    styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask
                                                      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                        defer:NO];
    [window center];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
    [NSThread exit];
}
```

by

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(prefsWindow:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

I would expect it to die cause its out of scope. Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to xcode, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window is still alive because NSApp still holds a strong reference to it, since it's the application key window.

Call close when you don't want the window anymore:

```
[window close];
```

Comment: You're welcome. I must be impartial: choose the one that you like more :-)

Answer (score 2):

When the window is made key AppKit must have a reference to it, so that it can represent it to the window manager among other things. It's likely that AppKit has a retaining reference—or that you've just released a window that's still being used by a framework so that a crash will occur shortly.

The one thing you know about window object given the above code is that *you* no longer have ownership of the window, not that *nothing* has ownership of it.